# PostGIS update SRID

Tags: postgis, postgresql

learning PostGIS, I have a table called nyc_neighborhoods and I want to update the SRID number to 26918

```
SELECT update geometry SRID(‘nyc_neighborhoods’,’geom’,26918);
```

this is my query..it is giving me an error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SRID"

```
LINE 1: SELECT update geometry SRID(‘nyc_neighborhoods’,’geom’,26918...
                               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SRID"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('roads','geom',4326);
```

*"This will change the srid of the roads table to 4326 from whatever it was before"*

From : http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html